# Significance index of unlabeled data prediction

Tags: classification, confidence-interval, svm, prediction

I have a training set used to train an SVM classifier, the model found is used to predict a dataset of several unlabeled examples.

I would like to know how to extract an index of the goodness of the prediction. 
I found some papers to estimate the prediction probability using the distance from the SVM hyperplane, but a distant example doesn't necessarily mean a well classified example.

Is there another method to assess this question?

Comment: Have your tried cross validation? this may help you test the stability of the classifier. The number of support vectors can be a good measure as well.

Comment: I've trained the classifier using cross validation and the number of SV is a measure of the stability of my classifier, as well exposed. I would like to compute an index to establish how well an unlabelled example is classified.

Comment: If you want to establish how well a variable is classified you need to consider how bad it is classified as well, don't you? Why don't you use the SVM results since svm gives an output $\in [-1,+1]$ ?

Comment: I have no idea about what unlabelled data belongs, it could belong to one of the two classes the classifier is trained on or be another one. For example, I have to classify apples and bananas using length and color, I have no idea about the fruits that I have to classify, if I have a melon it has high length and lighter than banana's color, thus it is classified as banana and is distant from hyperplane, but it is not a banana! How could I estimate how likely is a banana? I hope this helps!! Thank you.

Comment: What I meant to say is that, once your classifier is set up, if you try to predict what a fruit is: you will notice that a result for a banana is close to +1 (or -1) and the result on an apple is close to -1 (or +1 if result for banana is -1). Now you try and predict the result for the unknown fruit (it could be a melon, a cucumber ..etc ) and you see if it is close to either +1 or -1, if it is close to zero this mean that the classification is suspect for this one because it's as close to +1 as to -1.

Comment: Ok! That's great! Well in my software package, I have a as SVM output the distance from the hyperplane (positive for one class, negative for the other), but I don't know if an high value of distance from banana's hyperspace means a good index of melon, because it could be far from bananas distribution but farther from apple's!! I don't know if I am exhaustive! Thank you very much!

Comment: If you want to predict what a melon is using a good banana-apple classifier, the classifier should struggle and the prediction result would be very different from the others (if you check the distribution of the distances to the hyperplane for example).

Comment: Either a very short distance to the hyper plan (it cannot differentiate a melon from banana or apple) or a huge distance in either directions (in which case the classifier thinks the melon is a hell of a banana or a magnificent apple)

Comment: Yes, In the case of fruit classification, I would like to know an index that tells me: the melon is classified as banana, (ok!), but is distant from others bananas and is farther from apples!!

Comment: I've tried using Mahalanobis distance from the distributions described as multivariate gaussian, but I don't know if I have to include all the examples belonging to each class or drop from the distribution misclassified examples (if my approach is right!).

Comment: If you have $B_{i \le N}$ banana points and  $A_{i \le N}$ apple points, then you have $dB_{i \le N}$ distances of bananas to the hyperplane and $dA_{i \le M}$ distances of apples to the hyperplane. Now if you have a strange item (the melon) $X$, then I presume it distance to the classifier hyperplane $dX$ will be different from $dA_{i \le M}$ and $dB_{i \le N}$. If the classifier is a good one, $dX$ would be odd ( either too big or too low)